# How can get a select value when select is a query from mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

My question is how can I make a query from two selects of a form. I tried to do that with input tag and it was right. The problem is when I try to do the same but from selects tag (my select tags are dinamic because they really are queries from my mysql database).

So I have my html form:

```
<?php
require ("conexion.php");
//consultation:
$query = "SELECT * FROM workspace order by name asc" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM datastore order by name asc" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

//execute the query.
$result = $link->query($query);

$result2 = $link->query($query2);
?>    

<form action="yes.php" method="post" id="form" style="background-color:#E8FBFF; margin:10px;padding:10px;width:500px;">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Search settings</legend>
        Workspace &#42<br/>
        <!--<input type="text" name="nombre" value="" maxlength="10" /-->
        <select name="workspace" size="0">
            <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['0']?>">
            <?php echo $row['workspace']?>
            </option>
            <?php }?>
        </select>
        <br/>
        Datastore &#42<br/>
        <select name="datastore" size="0">
            <?php while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_BOTH)){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row1['0']?>">
            <?php echo $row1['name']?>
            </option>
            <?php }?>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And then I have my php file:

```
 <?php

//conection:
$link = mysqli_connect("server","user","mypassword","mydatabase") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
$workspace = $_POST['workspace'];
$datastore = $_POST['datastore'];

//consultation:
$query = "SELECT * FROM datastore WHERE workspace like '".$workspace."' AND name like '".$datastore."' order by name asc" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

//execute the query.
$result = $link->query($query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    echo $row['code'].'<br>';
    echo $row['name'].'<br>';
    echo $row['workspace'].'<br>';
}
?>
```

When I submit I get not any results.

Any idea??

Thanks

Comment: have you tried debugging? have you checked the log files?

Comment: querying from a select, usually means it's specific, rather than vague. Which, I don't know why you're using LIKE, rather than `WHERE col=x`.

Comment: if one of your columns do not match the `AND` criteria, then yeah... it's not going to show you results. try changing that to `OR` and see what comes of it.

Comment: Have you tried using `require ("conexion.php");` instead of manually coding the connection. Maybe there is a subtle difference in what is done in the `conexion.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly seems like we're blowing bubbles here, and a *magical* answer should appear below. *right*.

Comment: Either that or OP has spotted the problem and dissapeared not to be seen until they get to the next issue. Not everybody GETS the ethos of this site, some just see it as a free coding resource. We really need a close option that read `Questioner lost interest and question is now useless`

Comment: Its *only* been an hour...

Comment: The problem are not the conexion.php or the query because with input tags this works. The problem is when I try to use the select tag because the tags don´t show me results to selects ....